# Input from Scanner does not get transferred to variables?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

before I move on with the development of this application, I realized that if I split the program in methods as requested, I cannot transfer input into variable n . 
That's causes on grades() part, not to trigger at all the for loop.
I tried to put a fixed value on the array (ie. 3 instead of n) and it works, so it means that the variable n is still at 0 after I enter the input.
Adjusting the application to run all in main method works properly, but I noticed that I have to declare the variable inside the main method 
What I have to do pass the data into variable n? Thanks a lot!

```
//code removed
```

Comment: Please indent your code, explain what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead. Why would the for loop execute? Do you put anything in the `name` array before calling the grades() method? When this array is initialized, with `n` as its length, what is the value of `n`? Has the code that asks the user for `n` been executed yet? My advice: remove ALL the instance variables. Return `n` from display(), and pass it as argument to grades(). All the other variables should be local variables of the grades method.

Comment: Have you tried declaring a variable n in the main method, setting its value as the returned value from display method and then pass it as an argument to grades method?

Comment: This program seems to works just fine...

Answer (score 0):

You have globally initialized `name[]` array.
So what happens is, in the display function, when you enter the value of `n` between 2 and 25. it gets set to the global variable `n`. However your string array `name` is already initialized. i.e. it is of size zero. It does not get updated to size `n` after `n` has been updated by display function.
You need to include a line to initialize your array `name[]` after `n` value has been put in display function.

```
    n = in.nextInt();
    while ((n < 2) || (n > 25)) {
        System.out
                .println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Please enter a number between 2 and 25 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
        n = in.nextInt();
    }
    name = new String[n];
```

Comment: Thanks However if I specify exactly as you say i get "error: <identifier> expected" . If I fix it with String name[] = new String[n]; it says that the variable already exists.
If I remove the arrays from the super class and I specify them inside the lower class, it does not work. I need to specify them into the super class as after that I will need to create new methods to perform calculations and I need to refer to the length of the array, like:

 public double average(double avgCalc)
 {
  for (int i = 0; i < grade.length; i++)
  {
   sum += sum + grade[i];
  }
  return sum / grade.length;
 }

Comment: can you provide your code snippet for display function, after you have made the changes for reinitializing name array. Basically your name array is of size zero, you should reinitialize its size.